# How to prevent swimming goggles from fogging

Tags: exercise, swimming, exercise-equipment

Hopefully there are some avid swimmers on this exchange that can help me out here.  I recently have taken up swimming as an exercise since my gym has a great pool.  However, I have noticed that my goggles will fog up almost immediately.  Within the duration of one lap across the pool I cannot see anything at all.  What is the secret to keeping clear goggles?  Is it the fit?  The type? The brand? Are some goggles so good that they just resist fogging?

Comment: sooner or later they will fog

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised nobody posted the old classic: spit :)

Apply a little saliva to the inside of the goggles (the panes, obviously), and rub with your finger. Works every time. Well known among scuba divers.

Answer (score 0):

I find from experience that wiping the insides with a dry cloth and making sure they are water tight helps, but after a while the moisture on your skin will condense on the goggles so there isn't any permenant fix. Some goggles are better than others, I find Speedo's Powerskin range works the best for me.